# Rails root resource JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, routes

I'm having a bit of a problem. I want `posts` to be the default resource when navigating to my site (it's a blog:)

`www.example.com/ #=> posts#index`

`www.example.com/15 #=> posts#show`

etc. However, I want to be able to open up an API that I can use on my portfolio. I can use the `respond_to format.json` block to allow this:

`www.example.com/15.json`

but I can't figure out how to output the index action as json. Here are my current routes:

```
resources :posts, :path => ''
```

How would I access the index action with a JSON extension? Sorry If that didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean: how to write an url in your browser's address bar to get index as JSON?

Just keep your root index path to `posts#index` **but** allow API calls to `/posts/all.json` (you must code the `all` action yourself, of course) - you can also use additional subdomain `api.example.com` for your API calls and return only JSON formatted output for them, [like here Dailymile](http://www.dailymile.com/api/documentation#entries) is doing.

Also:
I think it's better for an API to have a *clue word* like `/posts/<what I want from posts>` instead of a blank index `/` - old, good saying that *good function name is the best function documentation*.

Comment: Cheers! I was just testing it out and came across this problem. In future I can just add an api.* subdomain :)

Comment: But what if I can't change routes, there is home page that needs to return some json, how then it's supposed to to be called, http:/example.com/.json ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need `:path => ''` part. In order to make an index of posts your root route, just do `root to: "posts#index"` (using new hash syntax).

In order to render a collection of posts in your index action, just do `respond_to` block in your controller action like so:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # render index.html
    format.json { render @posts }
  end
end
```

In order to access this index action via json, just pass `.json` as a format. You can also define a default format in your routes, like so:

```
resources :posts, defaults: { format: :json }
```

Comment: That won't work as I need `www.example.com/1` to go to the `posts#show` action

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, unfortunately, this isn't the answer to the question. :(